# Construind um For utiizando o R

Tags: r

Olá, acho que minha pergunta é bem simples, mas vamos lá:

Como faço um for desse estilo:

```
coef.matrix=matrix(0,4,16)

for (k in c(1,4)){
  for(i in 1:2){
    coef.matrix[i,1]=summary(lm(y ~ x))$coef[2,k]
  }

}
```

Ao invés de "de 1 a 4" eu gostaria de incluir "1 OU 4". Dá para fazer isso dentro do parenteses ou eu vou precisar chamar o `if / else`?

Comment: você está querendo fazer um `for` ou um `if`?

Comment: Se for 1 e 4, você usa for, tipo: for (i in c(1,4)){ expressao},  mas se for 1 ou 4, você provavelmente usará if.

Comment: Pessoal, obrigada editei o código. @DanielFalbel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz assim:

```
for (k in c(1,4)) {
}
```

Comment: obrigada. Eu editei a pergunta. Veja se ajuda.

Comment: nessa sua sugestão ele começa com k=1 e concluia primeira parte do for. Depois ele vai para k=4 e conclui a segunda parte do 4? N~Parece que no meu caso eles so considera k=4. Muito estranho

Comment: Neste exemplo você vai passar em cada um dos elementos da lista, os quais são 1 e 4.  Experimente rodar : ``for (k in c(1,4))  print(k);``